# Android studio, initiate task between timer schedule (JAVA)

Tags: java, android, android-studio, timer, schedule

I have attempted to create code that records a wav file every 30 seconds using a timer.

```
        t.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            launchTask();
                        }
                    });
                }
            }, 0, 30000);
```

"launch task()" starts recording the wav file.

The problem is every 30 seconds it attempts to start the task again while it is still running.

So prior to the task being intitiated every 30 seconds it needs to be cancelled right before.

The code :

```
   recordTask.cancel(false);
```

will cancel the task but I am not sure were to invoke it within the timer code.

Any advice about how to achieve this would be greatly apreciated.

Comment: Can you post your code for `launchTask`?

Comment: I think you have to finish the recording in `launchTask` when it reaches 30s. I.e.: don't make your `launchTask` lasts forever

Answer (score 1):

The problem I see is this is an anonymous method that you're creating. It's designed to not be easily accessible by the fact that you've created it as an anonymous method.

I'd suggest moving your "launchTask" method to a class of it's own, implementing the Runnable interface, and treating it as a thread.  This way you can start and stop it as necessary, as well as create (multiple) instances of it.

http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-concurrency/creating-and-starting-threads.html

At this point, you can pass your "timeout" to the class and maybe have stop itself. This is example of a class that stops itself from the link above. You should be able to include a constructor with a parameter that'll let you set the timeout.  You can also include any code to save the recording within the "doStop" method.  This way, you can make the class completely encompass all the code/methods you need for this feature in an clean OOP way.

```
public class MyRunnable implements Runnable {
    private boolean doStop = false;

    public synchronized void doStop() {
        this.doStop = true;
    }

    private synchronized boolean keepRunning() {
        return this.doStop == false;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while(keepRunning()) {
            // keep doing what this thread should do.
            System.out.println("Running");

            try {
                Thread.sleep(3L * 1000L);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }
}
```

If you need to manage the thread from the current location, you can do this (also from the linked page):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    MyRunnable myRunnable = new MyRunnable();

    Thread thread = new Thread(myRunnable);

    thread.start();

    try {
        Thread.sleep(10L * 1000L);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    myRunnable.doStop();
}
```

**Edit:**
I just remembered that Google is now preventing secret use of the mic and camera on devices. If the video isn't displayed, you aren't going to be able to use the camera, and similar for the mic.  I'm not advocating against your use, since I don't know what it is, I'm just saying to be careful what you're using it for and to be aware that there could be times when Google makes mistakes when filtering/searching for things it doesn't allow.

https://www.theverge.com/2018/3/7/17091104/android-p-prevents-apps-using-mic-camera-idle-background

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using `AsyncTask` and perform the 30s recording in `doInBackground`.

For example (some pseudo code):

```
class RecordingTask extends AysncTask<Void, Void, WavObject> {

  protected WavObject doInBackground() {
     while (recordTime <= 30s) {
        // keep recording
     }
     return wav;
  }

  protected void onPostExecte() {
     // Handle with your wav here
  } 
}
```

And in your activity:

```
t.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            new RecordingTask().execute();
                        }
                    });
                }
            }, 0, 30000);
```

Comment: This might not work on all versions of Android, as Android is preventing apps from using the mic and camera secretly. With this being a background task, Google's automatic checks for "secret" use of the mic and camera may be accidentally triggered.  https://www.theverge.com/2018/3/7/17091104/android-p-prevents-apps-using-mic-camera-idle-background